# Composition, aggregation and DI

Tags: inheritance, composition, aggregation

**Aggregation**: the object exists outside the other, is created outside, so it is passed as an argument (for example) to the construtor. Ex: People – car. The car is create in a different context and than becomes a person property.

**Composition**: the object only exists, or only makes sense inside the other, as a part of the other. Ex: People – heart. You don’t create a heart and then pass it to a person.

Does this mean with DI frameworks, *aggregation* is the preferred and more common approach, and improves testability?

Does this also mean the lack of multiple inheritance in a language like C# can be mitigated through the use of aggregation. I have always heard the discussion framed in terms of "*composition* versus inheritance". Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delegation** provides for a more flexible solution than inheritance - there is a good article called [why extends is evil](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html) that explains more about this  - however which version (whether it be Aggregation or Composition) is academic - you have identified the differences, and which one to use when is down to what you are trying to achieve.  Lack of multiple inheritance is usually mitigated through interfaces though.

Comment: Thanks - my question is; should the term aggregation be used, as the principle described sounds more like the definition of aggregation than composition?